# Symfony Console Questionn Helper - How to prompt the default value

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

In the [Symfony Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/index.html) component, using the [Question Helper](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/questionhelper.html), is it possible to automatically print the default value of a question?

For example, for this question:

```
$question = new Question( 'What is your response? ', 'Default response' );
```

I'd like something like this to be printed:

> What is your response? [Default response]

Comment: You could just modify the output at  `Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php doAsk()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in Symfony 2.5. The only methods supported are explained [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Console/Question/Question.html).

The only thing I could suggest would be to have a variable for the default response. E.g:

```
$default = 'Default response';
$questionString = sprintf('What is your response? [%s]', $default);
$question = new Question($questionString, $default);
```

Comment: I've actually opened up a pull request on Symfony so hopefully this should be good in the future.

Comment: What PR is that?  I'm not [seeing one](https://github.com/symfony/Console/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr).